# cache_form error: myisam_sort_buffer_size is too small

Tags: database

After running `mysqlcheck -udbuser -p --auto-repair --optimize --databases mydrupaldb`, I got the following error.

> cache_form error: myisam_sort_buffer_size is too small

Someone has [suggested](http://mattiasgeniar.be/2010/12/19/mysql-myisamchk-error-myisam_sort_buffer_size-is-too-small/) that it should be solved by increasing sort_buffer_size parameter, for example with `myisamchk -r -q cache_form.MYI --sort_buffer_size=2G`. Executing this command causes the following error.

> myisamchk: error: File 'cache_form.MYI' doesn't exist

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**mysqlcheck**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html) is a client utility that actually logs into mysql

[**myisamchk**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisamchk.html) is a client utility that does not require logging in. It does require

- access the raw file(s) needed, provided the datafile is not in use by the mysqld process
- your current directory is wherever the datafile is located

For the table mydrupaldb.cache_form, here is what you must do:

- Step 01) Run this query : `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';` In most instances, this will be /var/lib/mysql. For the sake of this example, let's assume it is /var/lib/mysql.
- Step 02) `cd /var/lib/mysql/mydrupaldb`
- Step 03) `service mysql stop`
- Step 04) `myisamchk -r -q cache_form.MYI --sort_buffer_size=2G`
- Step 05) `service mysql start`

Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT : The error message probably means you were not standing in the proper directory where cache_form.MYI is located at the time you first ran myisamchk.

Comment: Rolando, following your instructions led to: "myisamchk: error: Couldn't fix table with quick recovery: Found wrong number of deleted records
myisamchk: error: Run recovery again without -q
MyISAM-table 'cache_form.MYI' is not fixed because of errors
Try fixing it by using the --safe-recover (-o), the --force (-f) option or by not using the --quick (-q) flag". However, it seems to have been eventually fixed after running a through repaid command.

Answer (score 0):

### Try shrinking the cache_form table

On high-traffic sites, cache_form can get overly large. See this core issue: [Make cache_form expiration configurable, to mitigate runaway cache_form tables](https://www.drupal.org/node/2091511).

I've posted more information in this [Drupal stackexchange answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/260649/53059) on what to do when "Cache Form table size is enormous".