# How to clear form cache automatically?

Tags: 7, caching, cron

I am working on a Drupal 7 site. When I check the  `cache_form` table it reaches 4 GB daily so I have to manually `truncate` the `cache_form`  table. Is there any way to clear `cache_form` table automatically 4 times in a day?

Comment: do you have drush ? or do you ssh access to your server?

Comment: I have cPanel access.

Comment: You need to figure out why `{cache_form}` is getting so big.  Just pruning it is just fixing a symptom; you need to find the underlying cause.  It sounds like you have an anonymous form (contact forms, comments, exposed views forms, etc) and you have a lot of bot activity on these pages.  Bad Behavior or explicit IP blocking may be needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several method to clear the cache_form automatically.

Use [optimizedb](https://www.drupal.org/project/optimizedb) module

> There is well-known issue with fast-growing table cache_form. This
>   table stores Drupal form cache and it isn’t cleared when you flush all
>   cache or run cron. Also you can struggle with problem of fragmentation
>   with InnoDB tables on active delete/insert operations. This module
>   provide functionality to solve this problem. Also its provide
>   additional tools for maintenance database.
>
> Module OptimizeDB provide such features:
>
> ```
> Ability to clean **cache_from** in administrative page or do it by cron.
> Ability to optimize all database’s tables and display its sizes.
> Configuration of notification about necessity to perform maintenance tasks.
> Perform check and repair operation with tables.
> Prevent crashing tables when perform all maintained actions.
> ```

**If you have drush access**  Safe [cache_form Clear module](https://www.drupal.org/project/safe_cache_form_clear)

> Safely remove a limited number of items from the cache_form table.
>
> This module provides a drush command drush safe-cache-form-clear that
>   can be run at a high frequency, keeping the table at a reasonable
>   size. It requires that you use the database cache back-end for the
>   cache_form table.
>
> Drupal's core cron can have problems clearing out the cache_form table
>   when it grows extremely large. This module works around this by
>   limiting the number of items expired from the cache in a single run,
>   dealing with a manageable chunk each time.
>
> You can configure the number of items deleted in a single run by
>   setting the $conf['safe_cache_form_clear_limit'] persistent variable.

for automatically clear the Drupal cache use  [Cleaner](https://www.drupal.org/project/cleaner) module (it's not clear the cache_form table).

> The Cleaner module allows the admin to set a schedule for clearing
>   caches, watchdog, and old sessions.

**and another solution is create a custom route in your module** something that not predictable by others (some hash url), on call back function truncate 'cache_form' table (or equivalent Drupal ) then on your server or your Cpanel create  a [crontab](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm),schedule it to run the code periodically.

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to stop the form being cached completely?

Comment: You actually need some minimal amount of cache for forms.

Comment: @drupal  there is some hacky solution but it's strongly recommended you don't do that..

Comment: @drupal optimizedb is awesome and can do magic for big  databases.

Comment: How can we reduce the amount of form cache?

Comment: What do you mean reduce? If you are confident about your setup, you can write a simple hook_cron to delete records with timestamps older than _foo_ from cache_form. But it really isn't advised. Anything lower than 30-60 minutes is too low IMO.

Comment: @Kevin yep, I'm agree with you.

Comment: Here is an answer that explains the what and the why of cache_form: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/69842/57 - depending on your site, you can really nuke user experience. It would only be safe (to me) to flush anything older than 3+ hours. Again, it depends on what your forms and users are doing (commerce, brochure site, etc).